# Highcharts area graph adds whitespace

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using the HighCharts Percentage area graph and for some of my data, HighCharts seems to insert a whitespace. Please see my fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/jjaleel/54kWf/1/

```
the whitespace is near the 01/14 data point
```

Is this a bug in HighCharts? If so is there any way around it? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set min value as 0.5

```
 xAxis: {
            min:0.5,
            categories: ['01/01/14','01/02/14','01/03/14','01/04/14','01/06/14','01/07/14','01/08/14','01/09/14','01/10/14','01/11/14','01/12/14','01/13/14','01/14/14','01/15/14','01/16/14','01/17/14','01/20/14','01/21/14','01/22/14','01/23/14','01/24/14','01/27/14','01/28/14','01/29/14','01/30/14','01/31/14','02/01/14'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54kWf/2/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But I am still seeing the white space in your fiddle.